# Redirect, authenticate and get in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, http, redirect

I have a requirement where I have to GET a page using a url in NodeJS.

**The Problem**

The url redirects to a Login page where we have to authenticate using credentials.
Once we provide the credentials, it redirects to the actual page I wanted to GET.
This is how it works in a browser.

Is there a way I can get the final page as output?

```
    var https = require('follow-redirects').https;
    var options = {
      host: 'myURL',
      port: 443,
      path: 'myPath'
    };

    https.get(options, function(res) {
     res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            console.log(chunk);
        });
    });
```

I am getting the login page with a 200. Now, How do I automatically authenticate myself with the credentials I have and get to the page I actually want?

Comment: You would have to examine the login age and see how it submits the credentials.  It is probably with a POST so your script needs to execute that same POST and, if successful, it will probably get a redirect response.  You will also need to be preserving cookies because the successful login response will set a cookie which will be needed with future requests.  There are modules that help you manage cookies from the server side to simulate a browser client.

Comment: It'd be easier to do using something that drives a browser/PhantomJS. There are a number of packages that do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally achieved the requirement using casperJS. Thanks to the comment by @Dave Newton.

```
   var casper = require('casper').create(); 

    casper.on("remote.message", function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });

    casper.start("https://url.com/path", function () {
        //Enter Credentials
        this.evaluate(function () {
            console.log("filling inputs");

            var usernameInput = document.getElementById("accountname");
            usernameInput.value = "username";

            var passwordInput = document.getElementById("accountpassword");
            passwordInput.value = "password";
        });
        this.click("#continueFieldbutton");
        this.echo("login button was submitted");
    });
    casper.then(function () {
        var js = this.evaluate(function() {
            return document; 
        }); 
        this.echo(js.all[0].outerHTML); 
        this.capture('example.png');
    });
    casper.run();
```